# Single-quote notation for characters in Coq?

Tags: string, character, coq, notation

In most programming languages, `'c'` is a character and `"c"` is a string of length 1. But Coq (according to its standard ascii and string library) uses `"c"` as the notation for both, which requires constant use of `Open Scope` to clarify which one is being referred to. How can you avoid this and designate characters in the usual way, with single quotes? It would be nice if there is a solution that only partially overrides the standard library, changing the notation but recycling the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite confident that there is no smart way of doing this, but there is a somewhat annoying one: simply declare one notation for each character.

```
Notation "''c''" := "c" : char_scope.
Notation "''a''" := "a" : char_scope.

Check 'a'.
Check 'c'.
```

It shouldn't be too hard to write a script for automatically generating those declarations. I don't know if this has any negative side-effects on Coq's parser, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
Require Import Ascii.
Require Import String.
Check "a"%char.
Check "b"%string.
```

or this

```
Program Definition c (s:string) : ascii :=
match s with "" => " "%char | String a _ => a end.

Check (c"A").
Check ("A").
```